# php auto array new line with exception with regex

Tags: php, regex, arrays

i have text in variable:

```
$string = "foo
    bar
    cel
    [except this title:]
    one
    naa
";
```

and i need convert it to array but exclude "[except this title:]":

```
Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => bar
            [2] => cel
            [3] => one
            [4] => naa
        )
```

i have try this code:

```
$string = "foo
    bar
    [except this title:]
    cel
    one
    naa";
$array = preg_split("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/", $string);
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  echo "$i: $value <br>";
  $i++;
}
```

but display:

```
1: foo
2: bar
3: [except this title:]
4: cel
5: one
6: naa
```

i want display code like this:

```
1.foo
2.bar

except this title:
3.cel
4.one
5.naa
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where this variable is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$string = "foo
    bar
    [except this title:]
    cel
    one
    naa";
$array = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $string);
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  $value = trim($value);
    if ($value[0] == '[') {
        $value = preg_replace('/[[\]]/', '', $value);
        echo "<br>$value<br>";
    } else {
        echo "$i.$value<br>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
1.foo
2.bar

except this title:
3.cel
4.one
5.naa
```

Comment: yes it worked, and qeremy solutions worked too. thanks for both of you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array  = explode("\n", $string);
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  $value = trim($value);
  if ($value[0] != "[") {
    echo ($key+1).": $value <br>\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: it is possible to echo with include "except this title:"? display like my last code above?.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = preg_split("~[\n]+\s*~", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$i = 0;
foreach ($a as $v) {
    $v = trim($v);
    if ($v[0] == "[") {
        echo trim($v, "\x5b..\x5d") ."\n";
        continue;
    }
    echo (++$i) .".$v\n";
}
```

Out;

```
1.foo
2.bar
3.cel
except this title:
4.one
5.naa
```

Comment: sorry i click wrong accept answer. but your solutions worked too.